# Alfresco Rest API to download folder

Tags: alfresco

I have 3 folders and 1 html file inside a folder **sample** in alfresco. Is their any API to download the folder sample and its content. I am not able to find anything in google surf.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want the folder and its content to be in my web server. Any help please...

Comment: There are at least half a dozen! What kind are you looking for? WebServices? REST? CMIS? FTP? WebDAV? SMTP? IMAP? CIFS? etc....

Comment: @ Gagravarr Can you please share the REST api available in alfresco to download the folder

Comment: CMIS with the AtomPub binding is RESTful, see Jeff's answer for details

Answer (score 2):

The preferred API for working with Alfresco to upload/download content to/from folders is CMIS (see http://chemistry.apache.org to download CMIS client libraries for various languages). If you are managing content in Alfresco and are publishing it to a web server as part of a WCM content publishing process, you might look at the File Transfer Service (see http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/FSTR-intro.html).